# Find text autoscroll in MFC CRichEditView

Tags: mfc, find, richedit, autoscroll

I have an application with a CRichEditView, and I'd like to find text in it.

By creating a menu item "Find" with ID_EDIT_FIND, the view opens the find window and text is found by highlighting. BUT... the view is not scrolled, so if a text is found 100 lines below visible, that's where it stays.

Ideas on how to make the control autoscroll so that found items are always visible?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, answer:

ctrl.SetOptions(ECOOP_OR, ECO_AUTOVSCROLL);

That did the trick :)

Comment: +1 Well done for providing your own answer and placing it here.